# Example on how to do error handling for llvm

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I am using llvm 14 and I had looked at the llvm docs for error handling but I am still not able to understand how to implement it by using the CPP API. Is there an example on how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by error handling? How to create LLVM IR representing functions that use C++ exceptions? How to use the llvm::Error class?

Comment: @NickLewycky how to create error handling _inside_ the llvm IR. I took a look at [the docs](https://llvm.org/docs/ExceptionHandling.html) but idk how to do it by using the CPP API.